# VBA - Schedule tasks on oddly particular days

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

So I'm learning VBA with a lot of excel projects at work. I'm trying to see if I can get a macro I wrote to execute at certain times, autonomously. I've read articles on how to write a script to open the sheet and run the macro. That isn't so much my question, even though I haven't tried that yet, it's more about how to run it on the days I want.

My macro is based on other data sources, so I need to run this macro the day after coworkers have their deadline. The deadlines are the last Wednesday, and second to last Wednesday of the month. I need my macro to run on the day after, Thursdays, but how I reference that day is a little tricky.

Here are some examples of potential pitfalls that I'm trying to avoid.

A.) The last Wednesday of the month is also the last day of the month. This would mean that my macro needs to run on the 1st of the month.

B.) The month might include 5 Wednesday, like this month actually (8/2023) which would mean I can't rely on "third" or "fourth" wednesdays.

Does anyone have any idea how I could somehow run my macro on these days?

Comment: I would just create an array of integers of the day of year for each Wednesday in question. I would then calculate the current day of the year, and if the value was in the array, execute the macro. Isn’t the day after Thursday, Friday, which isn’t Wednesday.

Comment: Interesting solution to the issue.

My coworker's deadlines are on wednesdays, so I have to run my macro the following day, thursday.

Comment: So you would create a list of integers, for the day of the year, which reside on each Thursday.  You can also determine what week it is, then determine if it's a (Monday, Tuesday, etc.), and determine if you need to execute the macro from that information.  Trying to determine if it's "x Thursday" of the month is a more difficult problem then simplifying the problem set to a handful of results.  There are only a handful of odd weeks in a year. and determining what day of the week it is, once you know it's a week the macro should run is a trivial task.

Comment: Where are you trying to determine if you should run your excel macro? If in excel, then that workbook would have to be open and the vba script would have to be constantly running. If you are not checking in excel, then this question is really out-of-scope for this  group.

Comment: I would suggest you look at Windows Task Scheduler or consider an automation software like power automate/power apps. You can find the equivalent if you are using a different operating system.

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/task-scheduler-vb-script-to-auto-open-excel.302970/

My understanding is that running something like this could be done with Task Scheduler that could trigger a VBA script. Since I can't get super exact in scheduling in Task scheduler, I was hoping to achieve my desired effect with VBA or a mix between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer [@GeneMoody-Action1](https://superuser.com/users/1837691/genemoody-action1) provided led me to this solution.

```
Function checkIsFinal()
    
    Dim todayDate As Date
    Dim prelimDate As Date
    Dim finalDate As Date
    'Set date variable to last day of month
    todayDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0)
    'Subtract 1 day at a time until selecting the last Wednesday of the month. 
    Do While Weekday(todayDate) <> 4
        todayDate = DateAdd("d", -1, todayDate)
    Loop
    ' Run reports the thursday before for prelim, and the day after for final. 
    ' This allows for the last day to be Wednesday, and the day running the
    ' report to be into the new month. 
        finalDate = DateAdd("d", 1, todayDate)
        prelimDate = DateAdd("d", -6, todayDate)
        todayDate = Date
   'Checking to see if today is the date to run the report or not. 
    If todayDate = prelimDate Then
        MsgBox "todayDate = prelimDate"
        'Call Forecast1(False, True)
        'Call Forecast2(False, True)
    ElseIf todayDate = finalDate Then
        MsgBox "todayDate = finalDate"
        'Call Forecast1(True, True)
        'Call Forecast2(True, True)
    End If

    
End Function
```

This is just a simple function that will allow me to not need a check box on my form in excel, and I can call this function with a vbs script and task scheduler, if the days are correct, it will execute what it needs to do. If not, it will exit. Thanks again for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate all this with math, the month, day are numbers and the weekdays are constants as detailed here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/weekday-function

First day of any month is easy, last day is always (first day of next month)-1

From there you can see what day of the week it is, using the above reference if 4 you are there if less than four add the difference in days between whatever it is and 4 if over then subtract it.

References on how to do all the date math here.

https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/date-functions/

From there, on open, determine what  days you want it to trigger on and figure out if today is THAT day, run accordingly.

Or on open,  start a timer, and in that timer, evaluate and run accordingly.

Comment: @Patzy - You should submit a detailed answer instead of submitting what essentially is the a solution to your problem as a unformatted temporary comment

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the feedback.